# How to create a directory on my cloudfoudry account?

Tags: lucene, cloud, command-line-interface, cloud-foundry

I deploy to cloudfoundry an application which need a directory for lucene. This application failed to start because there is not the configured directory. I search on Cloundfoundry forums but i did not found how to create a directory on my server on CloudFoundry. If someone have a documentation or already did it, it will help me.
Thanks

Comment: Lucene should be configured as a Cloud Foundry service external to your applications. Applications are transient in Cloud Foundry, so direct file system access is strongly discouraged because the file system will not persist if the applcation instance is cycled, or if the client is load balanced to another instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah you shouldn't be creating directories inside your app.  Cloud Foundry works incredibly well with 12 factor apps (http://12factor.net/).  One of the factors is not using local storage but use an external provider.  I would highly suggest using a third party to do your Lucene work.

Cloudant provides Lucene indexes to users.  Also Cloudant has a pretty big free tier.

https://cloudant.com/for-developers/search/

Answer (score 0):

The advice to avoid creating persistent state on the file system, and to follow the architectural guidance of the 12 factor app (http://12factor.net), is spot on.

However, as of v183 [1] of Cloud Foundry, support was added for FUSE [2]. This can enable your app to maintain persistent state on its "file system". The following article [3] explains how to deploy word press to CF using this new feature.

[1] https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/cf-docs-contrib/wiki/v183

[2] http://fuse.sourceforge.net/

[3] http://blog.pivotal.io/cloud-foundry-pivotal/products/getting-started-with-wordpress-on-cloud-foundry